# How to move csv file from one folder to another in linux OS

Tags: linux

I want to move csv file from `home` folder to `tmp` folder in `linux OS` using below command:

```
$  mv /home/users_data.csv /tmp
```

But I am getting below error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/home/users_data.csv': No such file or directory
```

Kindly suggest me, how to resolve this error.

Hope for reply.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely `/home/your_username/users_data.csv` what you need or shortly: `~/users_data.csv`. So the error exactly tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two possible reason of this error:

```
1. The source directory may not exist,
(OR)
2. The source directory might be empty.
```